# Spring MVC - get only a single object from an external json

Tags: json, spring

i need to consume a RESTApi, which gives me a JSON output like this

```
{
"id": "e5d5ccc0-8da4-430d-b0ec-096d17ae2af8",
"car": [
{
    "identifier": "XX000YY",
    "formattedAddress": "Address 1",
    "lat": 45.841664,
    "lng": 18.199905,
    "isOn": false,
    "odometer": 763.4,

}
],
"location": "92589f4a-8c6e-4494-8548-b5428f8fa598"
}
```

Usually i would create a Wrapper Object

```
public class Wrapper{

private String id;

private Car car;

private String location;

//getters and setters

}
```

Then in my controller i would do something like this

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Wrapper> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,wrapper);
```

to get the response

But basically i need only the `Car` object, so i was thinking if there was a way to just return the it instead of the whole wrapper and taking the `Car` objects from it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866411/how-to-get-specific-object-from-resttemplate-exchange-method

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must create a serializable object like this :

**Car.java**

```
package com.wrapper;


public class Car implements Serializable{

public String identifier;
public String formattedAddress;
public Float lat;
public Float lng;
public Boolean isOn;
public Float odometer;

}
```

**Wrapper.java**

```
package com.wrapper;

import java.util.List;

public class Wrapper implements Serializable{

public String id;
public List<Car> car = null;
public String location;

}
```

After that, use a google API gson and use this instruction to get an object :

```
Wrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(response, Wrapper.class);
```